# Right to left icon menu navigation drawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, right-to-left

I want show icon menu navigation drawer from right but now it show from left please help ?

```
<android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:layout_gravity="right"
tools:openDrawer="right">

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layoutDirection="rtl"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer"/>
```

[image]

Comment: are you using arabic language if so then RTL(right to left) is used by the android os to automatically change the UI.

Comment: I have same problem. do you find any solution?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692792/how-can-i-have-one-item-of-menu-rtl-and-another-one-ltr

Answer (score 1):

Try using the attribute `android:layout_gravity="end"` inside the NavigationView element.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692792/how-can-i-have-one-item-of-menu-rtl-and-another-one-ltr