# How can I have one item of menu rtl and another one ltr?

Tags: android, menu, menuitem

I have this menu:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item
            android:id="@+id/choosemap"
            android:title="اولین آیتم"/>
        <item
            android:id="@+id/choosespinner"
            android:title="abc" />
</menu>
```

And this is output:

[image]

I want to have Persian title **rtl** and English title **ltr** (now both of them are **ltr**), how can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Use right-to-left mark or even left-to-right mark in the string when it's needed,

```
left-to-right mark: &lrm; or &#x200e; (U+200E)
right-to-left mark: &rlm; or &#x200f; (U+200F)
```

explained here:

[How to make the text direction from right to left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10964488/how-to-make-the-text-direction-from-right-to-left)

Example:

```
    android:title="\u200Fاولین آیتم"
```

Comment: How can I do this for my menu? Please attach code which is as desired in question.

Comment: android:title="\u200Fاولین آیتم"

Comment: If it works for you, please attach the image of your output. For me it wasn't correct.